Properly presenting a MFMailComposeViewController from SwiftUI
As part of converting a hobby project from UIKit to SwiftUI, I'm trying to present a MFMailComposeViewController from a SwiftUI view. It works, but the view controller isn't properly presented from the bottom of the screen as when using UIKit.
For example, following this answer by Hobbes the tige, here's the result I get:

With the original UIKit code, the same view looks like this:

Note how the bottom of the screen looks much worse in the SwiftUI version. Is there any way around this? Or a better way of presenting a MFMailComposeViewController from SwiftUI?
Here's the full code of a test application based on the answer linked above showcasing the problem:
MailComposeTestApp.swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MailComposeTestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

ContentView.swift
import SwiftUI
import MessageUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var result: Result<MFMailComposeResult, Error>? = nil
    @State var isShowingMailView = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.isShowingMailView.toggle()
        }, label: {
            Label("Send mail", systemImage: "envelope")
        })
        .disabled(!MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail())
        .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingMailView) {
            MailView(result: self.$result)
        }
    }
}

MailView.swift:
import SwiftUI
import UIKit
import MessageUI

struct MailView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentation
    @Binding var result: Result<MFMailComposeResult, Error>?
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {
        
        @Binding var presentation: PresentationMode
        @Binding var result: Result<MFMailComposeResult, Error>?
        
        init(presentation: Binding<PresentationMode>,
             result: Binding<Result<MFMailComposeResult, Error>?>) {
            _presentation = presentation
            _result = result
        }
        
        func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
            defer {
                $presentation.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }
            guard error == nil else {
                self.result = .failure(error!)
                return
            }
            self.result = .success(result)
        }
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(presentation: presentation, result: $result)
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<MailView>) -> MFMailComposeViewController {
        let vc = MFMailComposeViewController()
        vc.mailComposeDelegate = context.coordinator
        return vc
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: MFMailComposeViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<MailView>) {
        
    }
}


Could not replicate the problem in my SwiftUI tests. You could try using
MailView(result: $result).presentationDetents([.large]).
You could also try using .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isShowingMailView) {...}

That answer is showing not presenting

With fullScreenCover I can get it to cover the entire screen, but not with the rounded edges at the top etc. presentationDetents doesn't seem to have any effect. Perhaps the reason for my problem is that I'm trying to present the compose mail view from a view already presented, i.e. not the "root view controller"?

And of course, we are supposed to guess the reason, when you don't show any code.

My original assumption was that this is a generic problem with presenting this view controller from SwiftUI, that's why I only pointed to one of the methods I've tried. I've now built a small test application with pretty much nothing but the code from the linked answer, and included it above, showcasing the problem I'm experiencing.

Seeing the same issue with the PHPickerViewController confirmed my suspicion that this was a general behavior in SwiftUI, and made the solution easier to track down.
Turns out you must manually allow the sheet view to spill over into the safe areas at the bottom:
        .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingMailView) {
            MailView(result: self.$result)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
        }

This seems to work with any type of view presented in this way.
